# VC++ 6.0: too many actual parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, compiler-errors, visual-c++-6

I am working with a USB security key that uses a simple API. All I should have to do is include their header file and make my calls. I have a sample C program that works fine, and pretty much does this:

```
HINSTANCE hDll;
FARPROC dongle;
WORD retcode, handle[16], SD_p1, SD_p2, SD_p3, SD_p4;
DWORD lp1, lp2;
BYTE buffer [1024];
SD_p1 = 0x1C76; // example password 1
SD_p2 = 0x8078; // example password 2
SD_p3 = 0;
SD_p4 = 0;

hDll = GetModuleHandle("dongle.dll");

if (hDll == NULL)
{
    hDll = LoadLibrary("dongle.dll");
    if (hDll == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't find dongle.dll\n");
        return;
    }
}

dongle = GetProcAddress(hDll, "dongle");

retcode = dongle(SD_FIND, &handle[0], &lp1, &lp2, &SD_p1, &SD_p2, &SD_p3, &SD_p4, buffer);
```

So everything works fine with this. The dongle is found, and later calls to different functions on the dongle work as well. However, when I plug this exact same code into the C++ application that I want to protect, I get the following error:

```
error C2197: 'int (__stdcall *)(void)' : too many actual parameters
```

This is happening on the retcode = dongle() call. I don't understand why the compiler would believe there are too many parameters in my application but not in the sample application. I did find an [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117428) pertaining to the difference between using GetProcAddress() this way in C vs. C++, but I'm not sure if this is the problem I'm seeing here, or how I would apply that solution in this particular scenario.

What I need to know is how I can get this C code to compile in C++.

Comment: VC 6? I would strongly recommend that you update your toolchain to ... well anything else really.

Comment: Are you compiling as C when it works and as C++ when it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, we are actually in the process of moving our platform (which is dependent on several libraries that never behaved properly beyond VC6) to a modern environment.

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm compiling both in VC6, but the working code is contained in a .c file, and the non-working code is contained in a .cpp file, so I believe so.

Comment: @Geo : Well there you go -- your code is apparently compilable C but not compilable C++. What's your actual question?

Comment: My question then would be how I can make this C code compile in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a better type definition for `dongle`:

```
/* I didn't know what type SD_FIND was, assumed DWORD */
typedef WORD (CALLBACK *DONGLEPTR)(DWORD,WORD*,DWORD*,DWORD*
                                  ,WORD*,WORD*,WORD*,WORD*,BYTE*);

DONGLEPTR dongle; /* <-- need to change this type as well */

/* ... */

dongle = (DONGLEPTR)GetProcAddress(hDll, "dongle");

/* ... */
retcode = dongle(SD_FIND, ...);
```

Comment: When I added this typedef, I received the same error as with shf301's solution: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'unsigned short (__stdcall *)(unsigned short,unsigned short *,unsigned long *,unsigned long *,unsigned short *,unsigned short *,unsi gned short *,unsigned short *,unsigned char *)' to 'int (__stdcall *)(void)'

Comment: Updated to include changing the type of `dongle`.

Answer (score 1):

That article is exactly the problem that you are having.  In C a function definition with no parameters in it's list is a function that can take any number of parameters.  That effectively means the compiler does not check the number and type of parameters that you pass to the function.  In C++ the compiler always checks the number and type of parameters passed to the function.  So you need to use a typedef with the correct number and type of parameters for the function call.

So something like:

```
typedef WORD (CALLBACK* DONGLEPROC)(DWORD, LPWORD, LPDWORD , LPDWORD , LPWORD, LPWORD, LPWORD, LPWORD, LPBYTE);
```

Comment: I tried this and received an additional error: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'unsigned short (__stdcall *)(unsigned short,unsigned short *,unsigned long *,unsigned long *,unsigned short *,unsigned short *,unsi
gned short *,unsigned short *,unsigned char *)' to 'int (__stdcall *)(void)', which leads me to believe that is still for some reason seeing that there should be no parameters.

Comment: Interestingly, I also found this line in the API's header file: EXTERN_C __declspec(dllexport) WORD WINAPI SecureDongle(WORD function, WORD* handle, DWORD* lp1,  DWORD* lp2, WORD* SD_p1, WORD* SD_p2, WORD* SD_p3, WORD* SD_p4, BYTE* buffer); Shouldn't this definition suffice?